# How to join a sum from another table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I've a table with accounts and another with transactions:

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = Database.Accounts.TABLE_NAME)
data class Account(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = Database.Accounts.COL_ID) val id: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = Database.Accounts.COL_NAME) val name: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = Database.Accounts.COL_BALANCE) val balance: Double = 0.0
) : Model
```

Each transactions belongs to an account and therefore holds an `account_id`.

```
data class TransactionEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = Database.Transactions.COL_ID) val id: Long = 0L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = Database.Transactions.COL_TITLE) val title: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = Database.Transactions.COL_DATE) val date: LocalDate = LocalDate.MIN,
    @ColumnInfo(name = Database.Transactions.COL_VALUE) val value: Double = 0.0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = Database.Transactions.COL_NOTES) val notes: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = Database.Transactions.COL_TYPE) @TransactionType val type: Int = TransactionType.EARNING,
    @ColumnInfo(name = Database.Transactions.COL_ACCOUNT_ID) val accountId: Long = Account.DEFAULT_ACCOUNT_ID,
    @ColumnInfo(name = Database.Transactions.COL_BUDGET_ID) val budgetId: Long? = null
) : Model
```

When querying accounts, the `balance` should be the summed `value` of all transactions belonging to the account.

How can I realize that?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I realized it using a AccountWithBalance POJO:

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = Database.Accounts.TABLE_NAME)
data class AccountWithBalance(
    @Embedded val account: Account = Account(),
    @ColumnInfo(name = Database.Accounts.COL_BALANCE) val balance: Double = 0.0
) : Model {

    val id: Long
        get() = account.id

    val name: String
        get() = account.name
}
```

And the following query:

```
@Query(
    """
        SELECT accounts.*, 
        (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN transactions.type = ${Transaction.TransactionType.EARNING} OR transactions.type = ${Transaction.TransactionType.CLAIM} THEN transactions.value 
        ELSE -transactions.value END) FROM transactions) AS balance
        FROM accounts
        LEFT JOIN transactions ON transactions.account_id = accounts.id
        GROUP BY accounts.id
    """
)
suspend fun getAccountsWithBalance(): List<AccountWithBalance>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this (assuming you want a running balance) by not using a join but by accessing the respective objects along with a query to get the balance at a point in time.

So you could have the following Dao's

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE transaction_account_id = :accountID")
List<TransactionEntity> getTransactionsForAnAccount(long accountID);

@Query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE account_id = :accountId LIMIT 1")
Accounts getAccountById(long accountId);

@Query("SELECT sum(transaction_value) FROM transactions WHERE transaction_date <= :transactionDate AND transaction_account_id = :accountId ORDER BY transaction_date ASC")
Double getBalanaceAtADate(long accountId, String transactionDate);
```

The first returns the transactions for the account.
The second returns an account accoring to it's id.
The third will return the SUM of all transactions for the supplied date along with all previous transactions (hence the running balance).

- Note names may differ but the above is based upon your code.

## Example

You could use something like the following (not in Java rather than Kotlin) :-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDB = Room.databaseBuilder(this,Database.class,Database.DBNAME)
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build();
    mDBDao = mDB.getAADao();

    mDBDao.addAccount(new Accounts("Account1",0));
    mDBDao.addAccount(new Accounts("Account2"));

    mDBDao.addTransaction(new TransactionEntity("Buy my first thing","2019-09-20 10:20",-25.46,"blah",0,1,0));
    mDBDao.addTransaction(new TransactionEntity("Buy my second thing","2019-09-20 11:30",-65.30,"blah",0,1,0));
    mDBDao.addTransaction(new TransactionEntity("Deposit","2019-09-21 12:00",100,"blah",1,1,0));

    mDBDao.addTransaction(new TransactionEntity("Deposit 1","2019-09-22 13:00",50,"blah",1,2,0));
    mDBDao.addTransaction(new TransactionEntity("Deposit 2","2019-09-22 14:00",150,"blah",1,2,0));

    //<<<<<<<<< previous code is initialisation and setting up some testing data >>>>>>>
    List<TransactionEntity> tlaccount1 = mDBDao.getTransactionsForAnAccount(1); //<<<<<<<< get the transactions
    logTransactions(tlaccount1); //<<<<<<<<<< invokes the logTransactions method as below

}

private void logTransactions(List<TransactionEntity> tl) {
    final String TAG = "TRANSLOG";

    // If no transactions the return after logging message
    if (tl.size() < 1) {
        Log.d("TRANSLOG","No transactions to process");
        return;
    }

    // First get the Account from the first Transaction
    Accounts currentAccount = mDBDao.getAccountById(tl.get(0).getAccountId());
    // Iterate through the transactions
    for (TransactionEntity tle: tl) {
        double running_balance = mDBDao.getBalanaceAtADate(currentAccount.accountid,tle.getDate()); //<<<<<<<<<< GET the running balance
        // Output the current transaction with the account name and balance
        Log.d(TAG,
                "Account Name: " + currentAccount.getName() +
                        " Title: " + tle.getTitle() +
                        " Value: " + tle.getValue().toString() +
                        " Balance: " + running_balance
        );
    }
}
```

## Result

```
2019-09-23 10:59:19.225  D/TRANSLOG: Account Name: Account1 Title: Buy my first thing Value: -25.46 Balance: -25.46
2019-09-23 10:59:19.228  D/TRANSLOG: Account Name: Account1 Title: Buy my second thing Value: -65.3 Balance: -90.75999999999999
2019-09-23 10:59:19.230  D/TRANSLOG: Account Name: Account1 Title: Deposit Value: 100.0 Balance: 9.240000000000009
```

So with no balance 25.46 is withdrawn, then 65.30 is withdrawn (-90.76) and finally 100 is deposited thus the last balance is -90.76 + 100 = 9.24.

- Note this is probably not the most efficient way, but it is relatively easy to code and understand.

---

## Additional

To actually join tables and get data from other tables you need another class so that you can have an object with the required member variables.

For instance to incorporate both tables with related data you could have a class like :-

```
public class TransactionWithAccountAndDerivedBalance {

    long transactionId;
    String transactionTitle;
    String transactionDate;
    double transactionValue;
    String transactionNotes;
    int transactionType;
    long accountId;
    long budgetId;
    String accountName;
    double balance;

    public long getTransactionId() {
        return transactionId;
    }

    public void setTransactionId(long transactionId) {
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
    }

    public String getTransactionTitle() {
        return transactionTitle;
    }

    public void setTransactionTitle(String transactionTitle) {
        this.transactionTitle = transactionTitle;
    }

    public String getTransactionDate() {
        return transactionDate;
    }

    public void setTransactionDate(String transactionDate) {
        this.transactionDate = transactionDate;
    }

    public double getTransactionValue() {
        return transactionValue;
    }

    public void setTransactionValue(double transactionValue) {
        this.transactionValue = transactionValue;
    }

    public String getTransactionNotes() {
        return transactionNotes;
    }

    public void setTransactionNotes(String transactionNotes) {
        this.transactionNotes = transactionNotes;
    }

    public int getTransactionType() {
        return transactionType;
    }

    public void setTransactionType(int transactionType) {
        this.transactionType = transactionType;
    }

    public long getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public void setAccountId(long accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

    public long getBudgetId() {
        return budgetId;
    }

    public void setBudgetId(long budgetId) {
        this.budgetId = budgetId;
    }

    public String getAccountName() {
        return accountName;
    }

    public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
}
```

and a Dao along the lines of :-

```
@Query("SELECT " +
        "transaction_id AS transactionId, " +
        "transaction_title AS transactionTitle, " +
        "transaction_date AS transactionDate, " +
        "transaction_value AS transactionValue, " +
        "transaction_notes AS transactionNotes, " +
        "transaction_type AS transactionType, " +
        "transaction_account_id AS accountId, " +
        "transaction_budget_id AS budgetId, " +
        "account_name As accountName, " +
        "(SELECT sum(transaction_value) FROM  transactions WHERE transaction_date <= '2019-09-20 12:00') AS balance" +
        " FROM transactions JOIN accounts ON transaction_account_id = account_id " +
        " WHERE account_id = :accountId")
List<TransactionWithAccountAndDerivedBalance> getFullTransaction(long accountId);
```

- **Notes**
- The variable names used in the TransactionWithAccountAndDerivedBalance class are different to the column names and as such the name of the column in the result set needs to be specified (i.e. `table_column_name AS class_member_variable_name`).
- This also includes column that uses the sum function in a subquery. Noting that this will always return the same value as the selection criteria the date is hard coded (for simplicity/demonstration).

---

## Final Addition

The previous query would appear to be what you are asking for (albeit that transactions for all accounts would be summed). However, it is likely that you want a running balance.

The **TransactionWithAccountAndDerivedBalance** can be used without change.

For a running balance (hence why the previous method didn't care about the account) you need to be able to distinguish the column names for the subquery (using `transaction_date <= transaction_date` would return every transaction as the value would always be the same (as would checking the accountId)).

This could be done by setting the name of the main query and referencing columns using the name as a prefix.

The Dao could then be (using **main** for the name of the main query) :-

```
@Query("SELECT " +
        "main.transaction_id AS transactionId, " +
        "main.transaction_title AS transactionTitle, " +
        "main.transaction_date AS transactionDate, " +
        "main.transaction_value AS transactionValue, " +
        "main.transaction_notes AS transactionNotes, " +
        "main.transaction_type AS transactionType, " +
        "main.transaction_account_id AS accountId, " +
        "main.transaction_budget_id AS budgetId, " +
        "account_name As accountName, " +
        /* The SubQuery to get the balanace for the current transaction */
        "(" +
        "SELECT sum(transaction_value) " +
        "FROM  transactions " +
        "WHERE transaction_date <= main.transaction_date " +
        "AND main.transaction_account_id = transaction_account_id" +
        ") AS balance" +
        /* Back to the Main Query */
        " FROM transactions AS main JOIN accounts ON transaction_account_id = account_id " +
        " WHERE account_id = :accountId")
List<TransactionWithAccountAndDerivedBalance> getFullTransaction(long accountId);
```

This would return the same result as the initial part of the answer.

For example, using :-

```
logOtherWay(mDBDao.getFullTransaction(1));
```

where the **logOtherWay** method is :-

```
private void logOtherWay(List<TransactionWithAccountAndDerivedBalance> twaadbList) {
    for (TransactionWithAccountAndDerivedBalance twaadb: twaadbList) {
        Log.d("TRANSOTHER","Account Name :" + twaadb.getAccountName() +
                " Title: " + twaadb.getTransactionTitle() +
                " Value " + twaadb.getTransactionValue() +
                " Balance: " + twaadb.getBalance()
        );
    }
}
```

## Final Result

The result (along with the result from the initial way) would be :-

```
09-23 15:18:00.868 4079-4079/? D/TRANSLOG: Account Name: Account1 Title: Buy my first thing Value: -25.46 Balance: -25.46
09-23 15:18:00.868 4079-4079/? D/TRANSLOG: Account Name: Account1 Title: Buy my second thing Value: -65.3 Balance: -90.75999999999999
09-23 15:18:00.868 4079-4079/? D/TRANSLOG: Account Name: Account1 Title: Deposit Value: 100.0 Balance: 9.240000000000009



09-23 15:18:00.868 4079-4079/? D/TRANSOTHER: Account Name :Account1 Title: Buy my first thing Value -25.46 Balance: -25.46
09-23 15:18:00.868 4079-4079/? D/TRANSOTHER: Account Name :Account1 Title: Buy my second thing Value -65.3 Balance: -90.75999999999999
09-23 15:18:00.868 4079-4079/? D/TRANSOTHER: Account Name :Account1 Title: Deposit Value 100.0 Balance: 9.240000000000009
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I actually wanted to realise this in a query.